# Javascript is not working when ng-repeat is used

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to `AngularJs` and working on a website. 
I am retrieving the data from Rest services in a page,I am able to display the data using `ng-repeat`. But the problem is I have a normal `javascript` functioning element in the page. It is not working when i include the `angularjs(ng-repeat)`. Suggest me to work on it.

Comment: Please post your code here

Comment: Could you be more clear?.. What exactly you meant with `normal Javascript functioning element`? `ng-repeat` is applied on HTML element and it works when you use `AngularJS`..

Comment: why you are using javascript function.why you do not put this javascript function to controller.

Comment: can u give example then will see the exact issue and here put that function inside controller

Comment: I have edited. Please check it..

Answer (score 0):

Well nowhere up above do we see anything about ng-repeat, however I can tell you its probably got to do with the fact that you're binding your click event on dom ready, and then angular is changing your elements which nullifies the click listener.  If you're using ng-repeat, you should be using ng-click as the handler for those events within your controller.  Angular takes care of binding the handler specified using ng-click at the proper time when the element exists in the dom. jQuery really has no place in this if you are trying to use angular.

Comment: <div class="row" style="padding:0px 5px 0px 0px "ng-repeat="x in list"  > This is how m using ng-repeat. Its very lengthy code so did not post. In list i have stored my retrieved data.. So where am i suppose to use ng-click? Sorry for the dumb question.

Comment: no such thing as a dumb question.

ng-click is used to add click handlers (usually specified from an angular controller.. similar to how you are doing with $(elem).on() ) and it applies the handler once the element is rendered to the dom. More information at the link : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick